# How to use Spark BigQuery Connector locally?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

For test purpose, I would like to use [BigQuery Connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example) to write Parquet Avro logs in BigQuery. As I'm writing there is no way to read directly Parquet from the UI to ingest it so I'm writing a Spark job to do so.

In Scala, for the time being, job body is the following:

```scala
val events: RDD[RichTrackEvent] =
readParquetRDD[RichTrackEvent, RichTrackEvent](sc, googleCloudStorageUrl)

val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
conf.set("mapred.bq.project.id", "myproject")

// Output parameters
val projectId = conf.get("fs.gs.project.id")
val outputDatasetId = "logs"
val outputTableId = "test"
val outputTableSchema = LogSchema.schema

// Output configuration
BigQueryConfiguration.configureBigQueryOutput(
  conf, projectId, outputDatasetId, outputTableId, outputTableSchema
)
conf.set(
  "mapreduce.job.outputformat.class",
  classOf[BigQueryOutputFormat[_, _]].getName
)

events
  .mapPartitions {
    items =>
      val gson = new Gson()
      items.map(e => gson.fromJson(e.toString, classOf[JsonObject]))
  }
  .map(x => (null, x))
  .saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf)
```

As the BigQueryOutputFormat isn't finding the Google Credentials, it fallbacks on metadata host to try to discover them with the following stacktrace:

```
016-06-13 11:40:53 WARN  HttpTransport:993 - exception thrown while executing request
java.net.UnknownHostException: metadata
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory$ComputeCredentialWithRetry.executeRefreshToken(CredentialFactory.java:160)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory.getCredentialFromMetadataServiceAccount(CredentialFactory.java:207)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialConfiguration.getCredential(CredentialConfiguration.java:72)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFactory.createBigQueryCredential(BigQueryFactory.java:81)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFactory.getBigQuery(BigQueryFactory.java:101)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFactory.getBigQueryHelper(BigQueryFactory.java:89)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryOutputCommitter.<init>(BigQueryOutputCommitter.java:70)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(BigQueryOutputFormat.java:102)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(BigQueryOutputFormat.java:84)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(BigQueryOutputFormat.java:30)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1135)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1078)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1078)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:357)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1078)
```

It is of course expected but it should be able to use my service account and its key as `GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault()` returns appropriate credentials fetched from `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

As the connector seems to read credentials, from hadoop configuration, what's the keys to set so that it reads `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` ? Is there a way to configure the output format to use a provided GoogleCredential object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - you might want to set:

```
<name>mapred.bq.auth.service.account.enable</name>
<name>mapred.bq.auth.service.account.email</name>
<name>mapred.bq.auth.service.account.keyfile</name>
<name>mapred.bq.project.id</name>
<name>mapred.bq.gcs.bucket</name>
```

Here, the `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.keyfile` should point to the full file path to the older-style "P12" keyfile; alternatively, if you're using the newer "JSON" keyfiles, you should replace the "email" and "keyfile" entries with the single `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile` key:

```
<name>mapred.bq.auth.service.account.enable</name>
<name>mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile</name>
<name>mapred.bq.project.id</name>
<name>mapred.bq.gcs.bucket</name>
```

Also you might want to take a look at https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery - which is much more civilised way of working with BQ and Spark. The `setGcpJsonKeyFile` method used in this case is the same JSON file you'd set for `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile` if using the BQ connector for Hadoop.

Comment: Exactly, it was about finding `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.enable`
`mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile`. I wonder if having as default, `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.enable=true` and `mapred.bq.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` would be relevant as it might be troubling for production configuration? Maybe providing an util on `BigQueryConfiguration` would help such `BigQueryConfiguration.configureBigQueryOutput` one.